# Why would I bother using accessor functions?

Tags: php, class, attributes, accessor

This is the accessor function:

```
<?php
    class classname
    {
        public $attribute;
        function __get($name)
        {
            return $this->$name;
        }
    }

    $a = new classname;
    $a->attribute = "Anna";
    $name = $a->attribute;

echo $name;
```

?>

And this is just a regular class without accessor functions:

```
<?php
    class classname
    {
        public $attribute;
    }

    $a = new classname;
    $a->attribute = "Anna";
    $name = $a->attribute;

    echo $name;
?>
```

Both of them provide the same result. I don't get it, in what case should I use accessor functions?

Comment: you would only require accessors for non public properties. now some would argue that all properties of an object should be private/protected. the magic getter function is called when a property that is not accessible is requested.

Comment: From [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.overloading.php#object.get): __get() is utilized for reading data from **inaccessible** properties.

Comment: In your example you are **not** using the __get function!  If there is a public member variable that takes precedence.  __get runs when there is not matching accessible property.

Comment: There is another question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6741595/php-get-set-methods which is a better match as a duplicate IMO. The question linked as duplicate is about getters/setters in general.  The use of __get()/__set() in php is a slightly different question (I use gettters and setters and try and avoid __get unless I really need it)

Answer (score 1):

1) It simply lets you control how and who can have access to the property. ( The property should be private when using accessors. )

2) you may alter the value depending on who and how it is accessed

3) You can notify someone when a property is accessed

Any many more ...

Comment: Thank you very much. As I read more it'll become clearer :)